# How to prevent octave from spawning in a new Terminal window?

Tags: terminal

I run [octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) in Terminal but whenever I use the `Octave` command to start octave (from an existing terminal session) or select Octave in Mission Control, it starts a new Terminal window. I find this behaviour annoying.

How can I make octave run in my current Terminal window?

Comment: How do you run it? Little more details please.

Comment: Do you use a .command file?

Comment: @Rob I start it by command "Octave" in terminal (already copied the app into bin folder), or by choosing from Spotlight or Alfred. They all end up in a new terminal window.

Comment: @DonyorM I don't really know what is a .command file?

Comment: A .command file is a shell script that can be double clicked and automatically run. I don't know much about Octave, but I know if I use a .command file it always opens a new wind. What kind of program is octave?

Comment: @DonyorM It's like a open-source version of Matlab, runs in command line or GUI.

Comment: How did you install Octave - How do you start from Mission Control - don't you mean Desktop?

Answer (score 2):

The actual script that executes when the new Terminal window is opened can be found at /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/octave-3.8.0.  This path will be different for different versions of Octave.  To have this script run when you run the octave command, create a symbolic link to something like /usr/local/bin/octave (assuming /usr/local/bin is on your path).

The command to run this would be something along the lines of:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/octave-3.8.0 /usr/local/bin/octave
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a shot at answering your question...

It sounds like your current **Octave** app is more or less a convenient wrapper for the scripts and such that you would otherwise have to run from the terminal to get things up and running. In other words, it's created for people that are trying to *avoid* interacting with the terminal directly (and since you seem to *enjoy* working directly from the command line, the app has lost a lot of its convenience).

Anyway, in my opinion (for what it's worth) your best bet is to ditch the Octave app and instead take a more hands-on approach and install **Octave** via a package manager like **Homebrew** ([here](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X#Homebrew) are some instructions you can follow).

However, a quick warning: Installing octave this way is occasionally a real pain-in-the-neck (and same goes for getting **Octave** to work with **GNUplot**). Though the links I've provided *should* be enough to help you get **Octave** set up the way you want, the installation process itself is not always, well, particularly pleasant (after all, those "*convenience wrappers*" exist for a reason). Just giving you a heads-up...

Hope this helps!

[Another helpful tutorial](http://jatinganhotra.com/blog/2014/01/21/installing-octave-on-os-x-10-dot-9-mavericks/) which is similar to the first link.
And still [another](http://ntraft.com/getting-octave-to-work-on-mountain-lion/) (the title of this post is pretty revealing...).